# Gather graphs in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have multiple Neo4j graphs in hand, let's say **G1**, **G2** and **G3**. How can I efficiently migrate all the graphs into one graph. In the graph, **G1**, **G2** and **G3** has label *G1*, *G2* and *G3* and never connect with each other.

I am using Neo4j 2.3 but 3.0 will also be considered.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

OK. I am actually using Spring Date Neo4j, which is hard to connect to multiple Neo4j instances. So I decided to put all the graph into one instance and distinguish them with labels. Is this clear enough?

Comment: What does it mean - to migrate all the graphs in one graph? Give an example of input data and the desired result.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to combine multiple neo4j databases into a single one?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Problem solved. I do the following things:

1. convet graphs to json file.
2. read json file using java and write to the final graph.